# Python 3 GUI opening another GUI on button click - not on start

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Thanks in advance for the help. I wrote a simple GUI, and want to open another GUI by clicking a button, "apple juice". However, the "apple juice" GUI opens on start.

Did I type anything wrong with my code? If not, how can I make it open only when the button is clicked? Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter

###############

win = Tkinter.Tk()
win.geometry("500x25")

Tkinter.Label(win, text="You've chosen apple juice!", font="bold").pack()

##############

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

# Label asking what drink

Tkinter.Label(root, text="What drink would you like?", bg="goldenrod", font="bold").pack()

# white space

Tkinter.Label(root, text="").pack()

#Choices

Tkinter.Label(root, text="Whichever choice you want, simply press the buton!").pack()

# Apple juice button

def apple_juice():
    win.mainloop()

Tkinter.Button(root, text="Apple Juice", bg="SkyBlue1", command=apple_juice).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As an aside, if anyone knows how to input whole blocks of code, not individual ones, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from a couple of misunderstandings.

Like Highlander, there can only be one mainloop in a Tkinter program. So when you're creating that other root window, it's going to be shown. Period. Also, it's not `.mainloop()` that starts showing the window, that's just what starts handling events.

Finally, unless you've done something terrible, this code isn't Python3, because `import Tkinter` will fail.

Here's some code that actually does work on both Python2 *and* Python3:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as mb
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.messagebox as mb
##############

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

###############

# Label asking what drink

tk.Label(root, text="What drink would you like?", bg="goldenrod", font="bold").pack()

# white space

tk.Label(root, text="").pack()

#Choices

tk.Label(root, text="Whichever choice you want, simply press the buton!").pack()

# Apple juice button

def apple_juice():
    mb.showinfo('showinfo', "You've chosen apple juice!")

tk.Button(root, text="Apple Juice", bg="SkyBlue1", command=apple_juice).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok thanks, will try this tomorrow. Also, I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04, which comes with Python 2 and 3 installed. Is there a chance this is Python 2? I'm guessing there isn't a way only to have Python 3, not both. Can you also explain what the try and except ImportError commands mean please? I'm pretty much new to Python. Thanks!

Comment: `Tkinter` was renamed to `tkinter` in Python 3 (among various other changes). I believe you still have to use `python3 <script>.py` on Ubuntu, though 3 is now installed by default. If you're new to Python I highly recommend going through the [python.org](http://python.org) tutorial first. That will expose you to concepts like exceptions.